# Does haveing multiple layers of tint make sense?

Tags: window, tint

I am getting my self a new car, and car dealer is making me choose from different tints. Now I have been searching online what's a good tint color and shade. Along the research, I've read a few people having multiple layers of tint, and now I'm asking; Is there any sense to people applying 2 layers of tint on purchase?

What I mean is, if they're trying to get it darker, why not get a thicker on in the first place?

Question to answer: Does it make sense in terms of durability/effectiveness to have 2 layers of tint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does not make sense because you can get tint in ever darker shades. If you want the ultimate in darkness, get some limo tint. Having multiple layers on the window is just asking the outer layer to show wear signs due to the extra thickness. If this happens you'll get tares and discoloration of your tint.

There are two considerations:

1. The extra cost of putting more tint on when you could do it more easily with one layer.
2. Putting the extra tint on your vehicle may make it a prime target for the police. I don't know the legalities for you in the Philippines, but here in the States, most have limits with which you can darken your windows. Before you tint your windows, make sure you are within your area's legal restrictions.

Comment: Thanks again Paulster! You sure do know a lot!
Had to ask, didn't see this asked in here yet. We do have a limit for car tint here, but if I remember correctly, private vehicles can go darker.